# C function to find iOS User 12/24 hour preference from iOS device settings

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

I am working on a date utility to aid the conversion between date and string.
I want to know is there any method in c/c++ which I can use to know the user preference for hours format (i.e 12h/24h).

Note: I am aware of NSDateFormatter option. I don't want to use NSDateFormatter.

I am already using NSDateFormatter along with NSThreadDictionary.

Have used c functions strftime_l() and strptime_l() for conversion, which is almost 20 times faster.

Looking for a C/C++ method to know 12/24 hour format preference. 
Don't down vote question just because you can't answer. Let me know reason for down vote.

Comment: y is the negative score ??
NSDateFormatter is costly operation.

Comment: Since you only need to check this once (or at least infrequently - how often is the user likely to change this setting ?), why does it even matter if this operation is "costly" ?

Comment: @PaulR user can change the setting during any point of time. And this settings is very critical for my app. And I can't keep calling NSDateFormatter to know it. I do have this option as last source. Please explain y negative score.

Comment: maybe you can give us some context for this code? but ye it seems like a strange thing to want to optimise

Comment: @Fonix Yes I am working on an application where memory and performance is bottleneck as there is mbs of organization data with legacy code.

Comment: It would help to know more about what you're trying to do. Why do you need to convert megabytes of timestamps at once? Normally one just keeps timestamps in a numeric (non-string) type as UTC and defers the formatting until it actually goes to the screen. You can't fit very many formatted timestamps on-screen per second, so NSDateFormatter being relatively slow seems like it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If you create just a single instance of `NSDateFormatter` and reuse it you save yourself a great deal on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access such a system-specific setting I believe you'd have to use `NSDateFormatter`. It's really straightforward code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]];
NSString *time = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@: %d",
      time,
      [time hasSuffix:[formatter AMSymbol]] || [time hasSuffix:[formatter PMSymbol]]);
```

I haven't tested if this works for all locales, but it definitely does for English.

Comment: I am aware of using NSDateFormatter and is currently being used. Please let me know if you know some method in c . Just for this I don't want to use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get this information. Your C/C++ code can access the system's locale to get basic time information (such as date, time, time zone), and potentially the default 12/24-hour settings (although I haven't found how to do this), but iOS allows you to manually switch between the two options, which goes beyond the C/C++ libraries.